# Interactive Notification not showing buttons ios 9.2

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I believe I am creating interactive notifications properly, but I get notifications on springboard/lock screen w/out buttons.  What am I doing wrong?

**AppDelegate:**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings! = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()

    /// don't want to constantly set/re-set when this function fires
    if (notificationSettings.types == UIUserNotificationType.None){

      let yesAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
      yesAction.identifier = "yesAction"
      yesAction.title = "Yes"
      yesAction.destructive = false
      yesAction.authenticationRequired = false
      yesAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background

      let noAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
      noAction.identifier = "noAction"
      noAction.title = "No"
      noAction.destructive = false
      noAction.authenticationRequired = false
      noAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background

      let stopAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
      stopAction.identifier = "stopAction"
      stopAction.title = "Stop"
      stopAction.destructive = true
      stopAction.authenticationRequired = false
      stopAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background

      let encouragementCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
      encouragementCategory.identifier = "GOCEncouragement"
      encouragementCategory.setActions([yesAction, noAction, stopAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)
      encouragementCategory.setActions([yesAction, noAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Minimal)

      let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Sound], categories: Set.init(arrayLiteral: encouragementCategory))
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

        }

    return true
}
```

Somewhere else, called by `application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)`:

```
notificationArray.forEach({

    let notification = UILocalNotification.init()
    notification.fireDate = fireDay
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.alertBody = $0["Encouragement"] as! String!
    notification.repeatInterval = .Month
    notification.category = "GOCEncouragement"
    notification.userInfo = [ "UUID" : $0["UUID"] as! Int]

    if #available(iOS 8.2, *) {

      notification.alertTitle = "Choices Encouragement"
    }

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

    nextDay.day++

    fireDay = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(nextDay, toDate: fireDay!, options: NSCalendarOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
})
```

To re-iterate the problem; notifications appear on schedule, but left-slide on lock screen doesn't reveal any buttons, nor does tugging down on home screen.

Any suggestions welcome!

Edit: thought it was simulator-only, but is on live 9.2 devices as well.  Other iOS versions work as expected.

Comment: have exactly the same issue, and also inconsistently: once it shows, then it doesn't...

Comment: @Async- Are you setting a single notification or a batch of notifications at once? I haven't tested, but I am wondering if in my code I am attempting to set more than the 64 notification maximum and the app is rightfully dropping them in a FIFO way, but is also somehow mangling the category info of those that remain...

Comment: for me I found the problem. I was having this method
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings() in two places in my application by mistake. And second function in time did not have action buttons to register. When I refactored, it worked.
Also beware of the limit of 64 local notifications, thus you would need to reschedule them each time in order to have enough notifications to cover your case

Comment: @Async- thanks! you saved my day! In our code there was also RegistereUserNotifcationSettings called somewhere else, I was trying to figure out why interactions doesn't work for 2 hours...

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? I'm having same issue but on Iphon 5s running 10.1.1